# Spring state machine - is it thread safe?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

This is an example State Machine

(State1)==>(State2)==>(State3)

With event "Event1" that transitions the state machine to State2 and then "Event2" transitions the state machine to State3

The action between State1 and State2 takes time. (simulate by sleep of 5 seconds)

If , during that "sleep" time a different thread arrives and sends Event2 then it seems that the state machine will ignore that event since it assumes that it is still in State1

I have added sleep just to emphasize the problem, but also if the delay in the Action is only few milliseconds , In a multithread environment it can (and does) happen

I know that I can use deferred events, but then I will have to use deferred event for each state

Am I wrong with my assumptions here?
Is there a better solution?

Thanks

[image]